# How to use Openmoji font in XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I would like to use [Openmoji](https://openmoji.org/) font in my document. I've downloaded `.ttf` file of font from the site [here](https://github.com/hfg-gmuend/openmoji/blob/master/font/OpenMoji-Color.ttf).

My document is the following:

```
%%% File `main.tex` %%%
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\openmoji{openmoji}[
    Path            =   ./fonts/openmoji/,
    Extension       =   .ttf,
    UprightFont     =   OpenMoji-Color
]

\begin{document}
{\Huge
    Hello, World! {\openmoji \symbol{"1F4D7}}
}
\end{document}
```

I use `xelatex main` to compile and the result is:

[image]

It has no color and looks different from the sample from the site:

[image]

How to make this font to look properly in XeLaTeX?

UPD:
[Symbol from the example](https://openmoji.org/library/#group=objects&emoji=1F4D7)

Comment: I don't have the impression that the color font is a standalone font. Ask the designer of the font how the ttf can be used.

Comment: I'll open new issue in project's GitHub